# How do I get a pig past the world border in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to get a pig past the world border, so far I have done the trick where you place a block at the last block of the world.

Then ender pearl past, then use a spawn egg and place it against the block.

The issue is that the animal just freezes and can't move. How can I unfreeze the animal? Or, if you can't, how can I get a pig (specifically) past the world border?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't supposed to be able to get past the world border. That it works with an ender pearl is a [bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-53602). Entities freeze beyond the world border, because they shouldn't be there anyway, the world is meant to end there. By default the world border would even kill them.

So there is no way to get them to move, other than teleporting them around or similar.